# Rules for saying "here" in French

Tags: grammaire

I've come across two ways of saying "here" in French:

1) Voici quelques conseils pour proteger votre sante.

2) Ce n'est pas d'ici.

When should one use ici and voici? Is there any rule or have I misunderstood the meaning of these sentences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Voici** is a contraction of **vois ici**, literally **see here**. You would use **voici** when showing something to somebody.